# urdfdom check_urdf

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use `rosrun urdfdom check_urdf` in ROS Hydro (Ubuntu 13.04) and get:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named check_urdf below /opt/ros/hydro/share/urdf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112081/urdfdom-check_urdf/) by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2013-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would seem that commit [e27ac3ba](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom/commit/e27ac3bacd42a89e6ae9a62cd64d9be2938b18c9) has changed the directory where the binaries in `urdfdom` end up in during installation.

They are now installed as 'normal' executables in `/opt/ros/DISTRO/bin`, meaning that after you have sourced your ROS environment, you can just do `check_urdf /path/to/your/urdf` in a terminal. You don't need to use `rosrun ..` anymore.

PS: I'm not sure if this was intended, so I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom/issues/20).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2013-12-20**:
Thank you :)